# How to use this data array from database in view? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I have coded this :
[image: get_post]

This is my get_post function, that gets data. Function results();

So there is more than one row.

[image: show_post]

And here is function that shows post, loading view and putting this data from get_post function.

But this isn't a single row. This is an array...
[image]

Here is var_dump of this array

I do not know how to work with this array inside view.

For example

```
...
...<a href="#"><?php echo $tytul; ?></a>...
...
```

Doens't work.

I don't know how to use this array.

How to get into it's elements?

How to loop them? How to get for example title from 2 row? Or loop all rows to get all "url" that it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in controller set a name for your data

```
$this-load->view('post', array('posts'=>$post));
```

in view use that name of the array

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    ...<a href="#"><?php echo $post->tytul; ?></a>
```

Comment: And how can I get to some element without looping whole array? For example title in first row

Comment: `$posts[0]->title`

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: ehm, but this doesn't work.

in view `<h2><a href="#"><?php echo $post[0]->tytul; ?></a></h2>`

in controller `$this->load->view('post', array('$post' => $post));`

And it doesn't work, got error

`Message:  Undefined variable: post`

Comment: array('$post' => $post)); dollar here in first was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code to get you data from controller to view:

```
$post['postinfo'] = $this->Devloger->get_post($url);
$this-load->view('post', array('posts'=>$post));
```

Try to print array in the view side:

```
print_r($postinfo);
```

you will get all the data in the view. You can get particular value from the array with its key.

```
$postinfo[0]->title
```

Hope this will help you!

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

```
Write code in your controller set $data as public and you can use $data using $this->data['set variable name accessing in view with this name'];

$data you can use in all post controller function    
post.php //your controlle
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Post extends MY_Controller {   
public $data;
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

 private function show_post(){
  $this->data['posts'] = $this->Devloger->get_post($url);   
 $this-load->view('post',$this->data['posts']);  
 }

post.php
foreach($posts as $post){  
 echo $post['title'];  
 }
```